# Gorm: pq duplicate key violates unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to learn go & Gorm currently so I apologize if i'm missing something obvious.

I have declared the following GORM Models

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    DiscordID            string `gorm:"unique"`
    SteamID              string `gorm:"unique"`
    SteamID64            uint64 `gorm:"unique"`
    DiscordNickname      string
    DiscordProfilePicURL string
}

type DeepLink struct {
    gorm.Model
    ShortURL   string `gorm:"unique"`
    UserID     uint
    User       User
    LinkAction Action
    Payload    interface{} `gorm:"-"`
}
```

I want to be able to identify the User that created the deeplink - this may not be the best way to do this.

When on a new database, when creating a second user using

```golang
func (m *Models) CreateUserFromDiscord(discordID, discordNickname, discordProfilePicURL string) *User {
    u := &User{
        DiscordID:            discordID,
        DiscordNickname:      discordNickname,
        DiscordProfilePicURL: discordProfilePicURL,
    }

    m.db.Create(u)
    return u
}
```

I get an error saying `pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_steam_id_key"`

Creating the first user using this method and creating deeplinks for this User works fine, but creating a second user throws the error. Neither user has a SteamID set.

Im wondering if theres any way to fix this or better structure my models to solve this problem.

The database is created using Gorms AutoMigrate function. This happens on a new db

Thanks

Comment: You specified SteamID and SteamID64 as unique, however when you're initializing your user you're not setting those fields to any value, and if your database isn't set up to automatically generate unique values for columns that weren't provided a value, they will get some default value assigned to them, likely a `0` in this case, which on the second insert will violate the uniqueness constraint. Either remove the uniqueness constraint, or provide a unique value for each record, or set up your db so that it automatically generates unique values for you.

Comment: ... or declare the columns as nullable, then you can keep the constraint and you do not need to provide a value if none is available for the user.

Comment: ... to have those columns be declared as nullable by only relying on gorm you may need to change the fields from plain integer types to pointer-to-integer types. But I'm not certain about that I don't know how gorm works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In golang if you don't set value for String variable it means it's value is ""(empty string). [Ref](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12)

Since you don't set `SteamID` then ""(empty string) set as value for first user.
Then when your trying to save second user `SteamID` column as ""(empty) then unique constraint violates because ""(empty string) is a not null value for database and gives you error.

**Solution**: Use *(pointer) for those fields in struct. If variable of *string/*int64 is not set then it's value `nil`. Also make optional columns nullable in DB.

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    DiscordID            string `gorm:"unique"`
    SteamID              *string `gorm:"unique"`
    SteamID64            *uint64 `gorm:"unique"`
    DiscordNickname      string
    DiscordProfilePicURL string
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works, Gorm seems to automatically set the column as nullable when the field is set to a pointer, so automatically adds this change to the database while migrating

Comment: @TomHaines Welcome. As far I know gorm automigrate WON’T change existing column’s type
https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html